# strcpy segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, strcpy

i have a list of quads and they have a label starting from 1. the backpatch is taking a list structure which points at some quads. i want backpatch to update those quads, putting z on the char * fourth and then emptying l so i can put other quads later.I get `seg.fault` in backpatch's `strcpy` although I have allocated memory for the `char * z` and `char * fourth`. Does anybody know why does that happens?

```
struct quad {
char *label; //5
char *first; //30
char *second;
char *third;
char *fourth;
struct quad *next;
};

struct list {
    struct quad *quadlist;
    struct list *nextlist;
};


void backpatch(struct list *l, char * z) {
struct list *temp = (struct list*) malloc(sizeof (struct list));
temp->nextlist = (struct list*) malloc(sizeof (struct list));
temp->quadlist = (struct quad*) malloc(sizeof (struct quad));
temp->quadlist->fourth = (char*)malloc(30 * sizeof (char));
l->nextlist = (struct list*) malloc(sizeof (struct list));
temp = l;
//z=(char*)malloc(sizeof(struct list))
while (temp->nextlist != NULL) {

    strcpy(temp->quadlist->fourth, z);
    temp = l->nextlist;
}
strcpy(temp->quadlist->fourth, z);

free(temp);
free(l);

}
```

even if i only keep the

```
while (l->nextlist != NULL) {

strcpy(l->quadlist->fourth, z);
l = l->nextlist;
}
strcpy(l->quadlist->fourth, z);
free(l);
```

part, its also seg.fault...

Comment: Have you double-checked that the string pointed to by `z` is not larger than your allocated 30 bytes. Also you should not cast the return of `malloc`, it's a common source of errors.

Comment: [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org) may help.

Comment: make sure `l` is initialized properly. Cause you work on `l` after the assignment `temp=l;`

Comment: the string pointed to by z is not larger than 30 bytes(its actually 5)... i did not exactly understand what do you mean by not casting the return of malloc :P

Comment: For instance, `struct list *temp = (struct list*) malloc(sizeof (struct list));` should be just `struct list *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct list));` and similarly everywhere else you use `malloc`.

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: i did it without casting the return value of malloc...SEG.FAULT.....:p

Comment: That may mean you have neglected to `#include <stdlib.h>`, but it may also just be the same segfault as before.  Also, you *have* turned warnings on in your compiler, yes?  And you have corrected all the problems that this finds?

Answer (score 0):

from the comment:

```
//z=(char*)malloc(sizeof(struct list))
```

it looks like you allocated memory for z but it's become a non-NULL terminated string. So strcpy keeps copying and eventually starts reading past the end of z. Check what is in z befor strcpy

Answer (score 0):

You create temp and allocate memory for it and its components but you the throw it away when you do `temp = l;`  So all of these calls leak memory as you never use what you allocate or free it.  The two calls to `free` at the end of the function are wrong, temp no longer points to the memory you allocated and you don't free the other memory allocated inside the temp structure.  Freeing l destroys the head of the list your trying to update - I'm pretty sure that;s not what you intended.

When you do `temp = l;` you loose your refence to all the memory you just allocated, and now l and temp point to the same 'struct list'

You have `struct quad *next;` in the quad structure but as your list structure links the quads into a list what is this for?

Your while loop looks wrong to me - `temp->nextlist` is the result of yours call to malloc in `l->nextlist = (struct list*) malloc(sizeof (struct list));` but you never initialise the structure so l->nextlist->nextlist will be garbage and could point anywhere.

I'd suggest that you stop looking at backpatch and write a function that displays your data, doing that will have two effects, you'll know that the structure is correct and you'll have a better understanding of how the structure links together.  You need to get your head around how the structures and pointers combine to make a linked list like this.  Google for C Linked List Implementation and read some existing code that implements linked lists.

What is your code actually trying to do?

Comment: i am suppose to have quads(four strings) and *l is a list of quads. struct list is a struct that has a pointer to a quad and a pointer to the rest of the list. backpatch() must enter all of the quads of the *l list and put *z into the fourth string.

Comment: i ll start from the top: i have a list of quads.Thats why i need *next at quad structure. and they have a label starting from 1.Now the backpatch is taking a list structure which points at some quads. i want backpatch to update those quads, putting z on the char * fourth and then emptying l so i can put other quads later.